# Improving the performance of Page when it loads

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a .aspx  screen that displays some data in an asp:GridView component. There can be up to approx 30k records returned  when page loads.
it is taking appr 30 sec to retrieve the 13000 records from the database.IS this slow or fast?
am using stored procedure to retrieve the records from the database n am querying the database only once and storing it. then 
there is a foreach loop which is taking more than 2 mins to execute?
so it taking aapr 4 min to load the page.

I am just a beginner to asp.net .can you please help me out to improve the delay in when page loads?

here is the looping structure ..can we optimize it in any way?

List auditList = retrievedatafromdatabase();//This method returns records from database

```
               foreach (Entity obj in auditList)
                {

                    obj.CultSpecificRevisedData = "NULL";
                    obj.CultSpecificPublishedData = "NULL";

                    if (obj.RevisedData != null && obj.RevisedData != "NULL")
                        obj.CultSpecificRevisedData = ConvertToProfileSpecificFormat(Convert.ToDecimal(obj.RevisedData), DecimalSeparator);
                    if (obj.PublishedData != null && obj.PublishedData != "NULL")
                        obj.CultSpecificPublishedData = ConvertToProfileSpecificFormat(Convert.ToDecimal(obj.PublishedData), DecimalSeparator);

                    var yearPart = obj.CalendarYear;
                    var monthPart = string.Empty;
                    var frequencyName = GetEnglishFrequencyBame(frequencyTypeMasId);
                    if (frequencyName == FrequencyType.Monthly)
                    {
                        monthPart = new DateTime(obj.CalendarYear, GetMonthNumber(obj.Month), 1).ToString("MMM");
                        obj.CultSpecificPeriod = monthPart + "-" + yearPart.ToString();
                    }
                    if (frequencyName == FrequencyType.Quarterly)
                    {
                      UserMessage = obj.QuarterName;
                        obj.CultSpecificPeriod = UserMessage + "-" + yearPart.ToString();
                    }
                    else if (frequencyName == FrequencyType.BiAnnually)
                    {
                        UserMessage = obj.SemesterName;
                        obj.CultSpecificPeriod = UserMessage + "-" + yearPart.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        obj.CultSpecificPeriod = yearPart.ToString();
                    }


                }
```

Comment: Paging. You need to page the data.. Can you show us your code that you're using at the moment?

Comment: In addition to paging. Is it taking 30 sec to retrieve or does that include render? Viewstate with grids can get quite large making the page bloat.

Comment: Paging is added.Yes it is taking 30 sec to retrieve then am runnnig foreach loop on the retrieved data which is taking more than almost 2 min.

Comment: Paging is enabled.Once all the records are retrieved then runnnig foreach loop on the retrieved data which is taking more than almost 2 min then am displaying using data grid.
I have purposed a solution like returning only the first 100\1000 and giving good search and filter capabilities  as a work around but my boss wants to know if there is scope for improving the performance of the screen/data query?
Is there any scope for improving performance of looping or Store procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Paging is your first option.

But you should consinder the following:
Do you really need 30K records ? 
users don't usually go through the first 10\20 records, try returning only the first 100\1000 and giving good search and filter capabilities that will limit the result set scientifically.

I had the same problem and I understood that the users dose not need that many results they need a good way of finding what they want out of these results.

of course that could be incorporated together with paging.

If paging dosen't suit your solution (for some reason) The you do not agree with what was said, post some code and we'll try to help with performance optimization. keep in mind that it's a very hard task sometimes.

Comment: Paging is enabled.Once all the records are retrieved then runnnig foreach loop on the retrieved data which is taking more than almost 2 min then am displaying using data grid.
I have purposed the same idea as you have mentioned like returning only the first 100\1000 and giving good search and filter capabilities  as a work around but my boss wants to know if there is scope for improving the performance of the screen/data query?

Comment: Is there any scope for improving performance of looping or Store procedure?

Comment: Show your code for both the SQL and the .NET and I'll tkae a loot there is always room for performance optimization i.e indexing for SQL and using LINQ in C# ...

Comment: looping structure added to the Question.can you pls help me out?

Comment: There is just too much going on inside the loop. consider that some properties getters contain more logic to them that will result in a lot of computation, then you have conversions going on that are parsing strings, just for the heck of it try removing them from the loop see how much time it saves you and if that saves a lot see how can you avoid them ...

Comment: P.S Try using LINQ to structure your code using where and select methods, that might work faster.

Comment: is there any way we can run the looping structure like parallel while other methods are executing ?

Comment: It could run in it's out thread but that would be a problem if there is another method that expects it's response... and unforteantlly for you there is .. the html response is constructed according to that data so the server could not construct the result unless it ends.

Comment: I have figured it out the GetEnglishFrequencyBame(frequencyTypeMasId) which is being called in every iteration,its not required in every iteration.so moved out of the loop.now i can see increase in performance. Thanks for your valuable inputs..cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo comments about not really needing 30K records. Research shows that humans can't really visually process anything more than about 2000 list items, and if you're showing more than this you're effectively lying to your users by encouraging them to get a *false* or *incomplete* sense of the data.

But if you persist in doing this, what you want to do is iterate through the records set by hand, use Response.Write() to manually compose the html for each row and send it to the browser, and then use a counter to call Response.Flush() every now and then. Bonus points if your data layer supports streaming the data from your database as well (ie: via a datareader) rather than loading the entire result set into RAM.